# Code to Delete row from given customized listview using alertbox displayed when checkbox is checked in android programming

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

This is my code below 
 1) This is Class with getter and setter methods + extension of base adapter

```
package virtual.mall;

import java.util.List;

import virtual.mall.Salt_page_ada.saltlist_holder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

 class Order1_cls {


      String o1_it_name,o1_it_count;
     int o1_it_cost,o1_it_qty;

   Boolean o1isselect=false;
 public Order1_cls(String o1_it_name,String o1_it_count,int o1_it_qty,int o1_it_cost){
       super();
       this.o1_it_name = o1_it_name;
       this.o1_it_count=o1_it_count;
       this.o1_it_qty=o1_it_qty;
       this.o1_it_cost = o1_it_cost;
       this.o1isselect=o1isselect;
  }
public String getO1_it_name() {
    return o1_it_name;
}
public void setO1_it_name(String o1_it_name) {
    this.o1_it_name = o1_it_name;
}
public String getO1_it_count() {
    return o1_it_count;
}
public void setO1_it_count(String o1_it_count) {
    this.o1_it_count = o1_it_count;
}
public int getO1_it_cost() {
    return o1_it_cost;
}
public void setO1_it_cost(int o1_it_cost) {
    this.o1_it_cost = o1_it_cost;
}
public int getO1_it_qty() {
    return o1_it_qty;
}
public void setO1_it_qty(int o1_it_qty) {
    this.o1_it_qty = o1_it_qty;
}
public Boolean getO1isselect() {
    return o1isselect;
}
public void setO1isselect(Boolean o1isselect) {
    this.o1isselect = o1isselect;
}


}
public class Order1_page extends ArrayAdapter<Order1_cls> {
    private List <Order1_cls> order1list;
    private Context context;
    public Order1_page(List<Order1_cls> order1list, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.order1listref,order1list);
        this.order1list=order1list;
         this.context=context;

}
    public static class Order1list_holder{

        public TextView o1_name;
        public TextView o1_count;
        public TextView o1_qty;
        public TextView o1_cost;
        public CheckBox o1chkbx;
    }

    public View getView(int pos,View con_view,ViewGroup parent){

        View v=con_view;

        Order1list_holder hold=new Order1list_holder();
        if(con_view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.order1listref,null);

            hold.o1_name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.o1_tv_name);
            hold.o1_count=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.o1_tv_count);
            hold.o1_qty=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.o1_tv_qty);
            hold.o1_cost=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.o1_tv_cost);
            hold.o1chkbx=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.o1_cBox);

            hold.o1chkbx.setOnCheckedChangeListener((Order1class) context);

        }
        else{
            hold=(Order1list_holder)v.getTag();
        }
        Order1_cls o1= order1list.get(pos);
        //hold.o1_name.setText(o1.getO1_it_name());
        hold.o1_count.setText(o1.getO1_it_count());
        hold.o1_qty.setText(" "+o1.getO1_it_qty());
        hold.o1_cost.setText(" " + o1.getO1_it_cost());
        hold.o1chkbx.setChecked(o1.o1isselect);
        hold.o1chkbx.setTag(o1);

        return v;

    }


}
```

2) This is code for main class extending the activity with handlers 
i have written the code for deletion below but it shows an exceptio

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Order1class extends Activity implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener  {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Order1_cls> order1list;  //class name in ref java file
    Order1_page o1adapter;     // ref xml name
    ArrayList<Integer> positionslist;
    ImageButton addc,delbtn;
    protected Object posi;
    final Context context = this;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order1pageclass);
        positionslist=new ArrayList<Integer>();


        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.order1class_listv); //listview id in main layout
        disp_ord1list();

    }





  private void disp_ord1list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      order1list =new ArrayList<Order1_cls>();
      order1list.add(new Order1_cls("Rice(basmati)","1kg packet",3,450));
      order1list.add(new Order1_cls("Lentils(finegrade)","2kg packet",2,500));
      order1list.add(new Order1_cls("Colgate","5kg packet",3,60));
      order1list.add(new Order1_cls("cereal","1kg packet",3,60));
      order1list.add(new Order1_cls("surfexcel","2kg packet",2,40));
      order1list.add(new Order1_cls("vim","200gms Bar",1,25));
      order1list.add(new Order1_cls("Flour","5kg packet",1,300));

    o1adapter=new Order1_page(order1list,this);
    lv.setAdapter(o1adapter);
    }




    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton but_view, boolean o1isselected) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int posi=lv.getPositionForView(but_view);
         if(posi !=ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
             Order1_cls o1=order1list.get(posi);    
        o1.setO1isselect(o1isselected);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("remove item ??");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to delete")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        for(int position : positionslist){
                            order1list.remove(position);
                         }  o1adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("add",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        // Toast.makeText(this,"CLICKED ON " + o1.getO1_it_name()+"of count   "+ o1.getO1_it_count()+"cost is "+o1.getO1_it_cost(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
    }
```

3) order1pageclass.xml   file for actual page layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#58ACFA"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order-1    27/3/15"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/order1class_listv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lay1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="#FAFAFA" >

    </ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#58ACFA"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_btn"
        android:background="#58ACFA" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:src="@drawable/home_btn"
        android:background="#58ACFA"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cart_btn"
        android:background="#58ACFA" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

4) reference page layout  (how each row should look or what it must have )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o1_tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Rice(Basmati)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/o1_cBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="+ Cart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o1_tv_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/o1_tv_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/o1_tv_name"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="5kg Pack"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o1_tv_qty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/o1_tv_count"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/o1_tv_count"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/o1_cBox"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvqty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/o1_tv_qty"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/o1_tv_qty"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/o1_tv_name"
        android:text="Qty :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o1_tv_cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/o1_tv_qty"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/o1_tv_qty"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/o1_cBox"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="450 "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Cannot delete the row on button click . 
do u need xml too ? 
all i need is code to delete the selected row on button click

Comment: If you want to delete item from listview then write onItemClickListener for listview itself.

Comment: ` final int position = lv.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());` in this code the view passed to it must be an adapter item or a descendant of an adapter item.

Comment: no , actually i have checkboxes for each row..
i want to DELETE THE ROW with checked box..
when i click ANOTHER BUTTON

Comment: @boss ..thats what im actually confused with ,
can you please put the code lines that woould be so kind of you

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCheckedChanged()` method save the positions in a list. and when button is clicked iterate through the list and delete them from the adapter list.

Comment: should i create a class position list again ?? 
if so , in which file ? @nag

Comment: No.. just a list (eg: ArrayList) to store the checked view's positions.